# Background Image Stretched when taping text filed inside scroll view

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I created one registration page using relative layout and applied background image to main layout. Here I used scroll view for scrolling my contents.

**Problem:** when I selected my textfield, background image of main relative layout stretched.

**Here is my xml content:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:androidcustomfont="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cpt.realtor.activity"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="615dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="680dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/realtor_land_text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
            style="@style/activity_realtor_details_of_registration_tabletversion_for_textboxes"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/firstname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editLastName"
            style="@style/activity_realtor_details_of_registration_tabletversion_for_textboxes"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editFirstName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/lastname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCompany"
            style="@style/activity_realtor_details_of_registration_tabletversion_for_textboxes"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editLastName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/company"
            android:inputType="text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editMobile"
            style="@style/activity_realtor_details_of_registration_tabletversion_for_textboxes"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editCompany"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/mobile"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editEmail"
            style="@style/activity_realtor_details_of_registration_tabletversion_for_textboxes"
            android:layout_width="440dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editMobile"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerForStates"
        android:layout_width="440dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerForStates"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:text="@string/receivealert"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.cpt.realtor.utility.CustomFontButton
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share_btn_selector"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            androidcustomfont:customFontView="clarendon_regular.ttf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSkip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/skip_this_step"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/splitter"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSkip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    <View
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSkip"
            android:background="@drawable/footer" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**without selecting TextField:**
[image]

**After selecting TextField:**
[image]

In my second image, the background image stretched. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show us that `background` drawable, if it is a XML?

Comment: It's just drawable image

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest write this in activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```